# Python - call method in subclass

Tags: python

I am using a simpleWebSocket server class and have a 1 second interval timer that I would like to call methods in a couple of different classes.

the wsscb() class is the handler for the SimpleWebSocketServer(), how can I call a method from the wss() object from another object such as the udt() timer ?

Calling wss.wsscb().myfunc() results in an error: "AttributeError: 'SimpleWebSocketServer' object has no attribute 'wsscb'"

calling wsscb.myfunc() results in: TypeError: unbound method myfunc() must be called with wsscb instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

```
class wsscb(WebSocket):
  def __init__(self, server, sock, address):
    WebSocket.__init__(self, server, sock, address)

  def myfunc(self):
    self.send('some data')

  def handleMessage(self):
    pass

  def handleConnected(self):
    pass

class udt(Thread):
  def __init__(self, event):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.stopped = event

  def run(self):
    while not self.stopped.wait(1.00):
      wss.wsscb().myfunc()
      xxx.yyy()().anotherfunc()


## Main
wss = SimpleWebSocketServer('', 4545,wsscb)

## Start Timer
stopFlag = Event()
self.udt = udt(stopFlag)
self.udt.start()    

wss.serveforever()
```

Comment: Why do you do `wss.wsscb`? The error says `wsscb` is not an attribute of `wss`.

Comment: WHy not just wsscb.myfunc()? Also, what library is this, did you create the SimpleWebSocketServer class, or what's it from?

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to call myfunc() from the object wss

Comment: Why do you need to call `myfunc` on run? I'm not sure I understand. I thought `wsscb` would be initialized by your socket server whenever a request hit your socket server.

Comment: I never used this library, but I took a look at their simple example: http://opiate.github.io/SimpleWebSocketServer/ (I think that's the library you're using)

Comment: @crankshaft, why do you need to do `wss.wsscb().myfunc()`? Why not just do `wsscb.myfunc()`

Comment: udt is a seperate class that is basically an interval time that runs once a second, from this interval timer I would like to call the myfunc() method of wsscb() which is a subclass of simpleSocketServer()

Comment: wsscb.myfunc() results in: TypeError: unbound method myfunc() must be called with wsscb instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple problems.

`wss.wsscb()` isn't valid. Typing that means you're trying to call a function in wss called `wsscb()`. `wss` is a SimpleWebSocketServer, and there is no function called `wsscb()`. A function is not the same as calling an object.

`wsscb()` won't work either, because in your class, you're saying it's takes a `WebSocket` object, which I assume takes some parameters, so you need to pass it those.

I think it would be best to make a subclass of `SimpleWebSocketServer` (instead of `WebSocket`), and put your custom function in there. Your comment says "wsscb() is a subclass of SimpleSocketServer", but it is not. It's a subclass of `WebSocket`.

You also never created an object of type wsscb.

If you can explain what you're specifically trying to achieve, and what `myfunc()` is, we may be able to help more

Also, you really shouldn't subclass `Thread`. Scrap the `udt` class you made and instead

```
def myfunc(wsscb_object):
     while True:
         time.sleep(1)
         wsscb_object.myfunc()
         #whatever else you want

 wsscb_object = wsscb(#pass the parameters)
 thread = Thread(target=myfunc, args=(some_socket))
 thread.start()
```

You may also want to read up more on inheritance:

- [python subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290323/python-subclasses)
- http://www.jesshamrick.com/2011/05/18/an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python/
- [Using inheritance in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128833/using-inheritance-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for helping, this is only a code snippet, I am running the websocket server forever, and every second I want to send a message to connected clients from the udt class, myfunc will call the self.send() method to transmit some data to the connected client

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/660974/380451 for a better way to handle threading. There's really no reason to subclass `Thread`